# Ajax delete cell from row, recalculate rows moving cell onto next row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the twitter bootstrap row/table structure with dynamic cell widths and I have a ajax scripts which delete a record from the database and removes the HTML.

But how would I go about re-calculating the rows after the delete? This is the part I cant get my head around the logic process.

E.g: If I delete a cell from the middle row, it would calculate if there was enough space available after the delete and move the cell onto the next line. Then loop onto next line/etc

Ideally it would be really cool if it worked with dynamic widths, so that all the spans add up to 12. It would only move an item onto the next row if there is definitely room.

If I delete a big/wide span and there was room for 2 small spans from the next line to replace. Etc I think you get the idea here.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span4">...<a href="">Delete</a></div>
   <div class="span4">...<a href="">Delete</a></div>
   <div class="span4">...<a href="">Delete</a></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="span6">...<a href="">Delete</a></div>
   <div class="span2">...<a href="">Delete</a></div>
   <div class="span4">...<a href="">Delete</a></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="span2">...<a href="">Delete</a></div>
   <div class="span8">...<a href="">Delete</a></div>
   <div class="span2">...<a href="">Delete</a></div>
</div>

    $('a').click(function(e){    
    e.preventDefault();
    var $self = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxAction,
        data: obj,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR){
            if(data && data.ok){
                $self.parent().slideUp("slow", function(){
                    if(delete_container.substring(0,5) == ".span"){

                        // get parent row
                        var row = $(this).parent();
                        if(row.hasClass("row") || row.hasClass("row-fluid")){
                            var count = 0;
                            row.children("[class*='span']").each(function(){

                                count = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/);                                     

                            });

                            if(count < 12){
                                // check next line and move item up if it fits
                                // then loop over everything again on the next row
                            }
                        }                               
                    }
                    $(this).remove(); 
                })
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not looking for somebody to write everything here, just give me some points on how it could work. Finding it hard to get my heard around the logic

Comment: I dont know i correctly understand you, lets check: For example there is table 3 cols 3 rows. You are now deleting cell in first row and second column (position [1,2]). And now you want to chec if there is enought space in first row for cell [2,1] (second row first column), put it there?

Comment: Exactly yes, then it would loop onto the third row where there would be space to now move 2 cell onto the next row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way: change structure of your table, and delete `<div class="row">`, then add `float: left` to your cells. Browser will take care on everything. :)

But if its unacceptable, lets make function called `rearrangeTable( fromRow )`:

```
rearrangeTable( fromRow ) { //from row is a number of row, where you have deleted cell.
var $actualRow = $('div.row:eq('+fromRow+')');
var $nextRow = $actualRow.next(div.row);

//getting free space in actual row
var freeSpace = $actualRow.width(); //IMPORTANT: width() not outerWidth()
$actualRow.find('cell_selector :)').each( function(i) {
    freeSpace -= $(this).outerWidth();
})

var $nextCell;
while( $nextCell = getFirstCell( $nextRow ) ) { //ill not show this function its trivial, just returns first cell or false if there are no more cells
    var cellWidth = $nextCell.outerWidth();
    if( freeSpace >= cellWidth ) {
        letsMoveThisCell( $nextCell, $actualRow);
        freeSpace -= cellWidth;
    } else {
        break; //no more space, we can end there
    }
}
```

Its just metacode, not tested, showing an idea how you can archieve it. Now, you should call `rearrangeTable( fromRow )` from row where cell has been deleted to the end of your table and it should work.